# Fake the path of a file, in your <head>?

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a small question.
Is it possible with php to fake a path ?
For instance I have a joomla website.
any person knows how Joomla is loading assets ( like css / js or pictures ).
If you look at the html source code of a joomla website you will see ( http://joomla32.cloudaccess.net/ )

```
 <script src="/templates/protostar/js/template.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/protostar/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
```

Is there a possibility that I can say `/skin/js/`  instead of `/templates/prostar/js/` ?

This isn't only an issue with Joomla but this answer goes to all websites.
Is this possible with php ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at URL rewriting questions/answers, it might help you solve your problem.

Comment: It's perfectly possible with webserver mod_rewrite; but then anybody trying to know how the file is loading assets just looks at the fake path.... but why should this matter?

Comment: Even if you used a fake path, anyone who knows what they're doing will know that you're using Joomla to power your site and will also know the structure of Joomla's files. Therefore do you actually feel there is much point in doing this?

Comment: I have very weird clients, they don't want people to brute force or attack their website because it is joomla or drupal or wordpress.
If the fakepath is working me and my client will be satisfied, of course the loading structure is the same but it may take more then 1 look

Comment: Joomla 3.3 uses Bcrypt encryption, so trying to brute force that would take a lifetime. Showing a "fake path" will not prevent a  brute force attack anyway, might be worth letting them know that

Comment: I know that it won't prevent it, but is there a possibility to rewrite the url with php. I know that it won't make any difference but clients -.-

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to rewrite the URLs using .htaccess, however, it shouldn't be the task to attempt to successfully hide your directory structure but to properly give or not give access to these directories and files.

Comment: I know that it won't hide my directory. only show a different path in the source

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound so hard to to move these two files to another path.
As I could see in protostar template index.php, they are located at lines 39 and 42.

> $doc->addScript('templates/' .$this->template. '/js/template.js');
>
> $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/'.$this->template.'/css/template.css');

You could change the paths to a new folder (ex. assets):

> $doc->addScript('assets/js/template.js');
>
> $doc->addStyleSheet('assets/css/template.css');

Answer (score 0):

You could do what @emmanuel suggested which is perfectly fine for just template script/css imports, however if you're planning to do this for every know script and css file being imported on your site, then you would also have to start editing extensions and it would simply cause problem after problem.

Simple solution:

Download [JCH Optimize](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance/12088) which is a cache plugin. It has the ability to comine all your Javascript and CSS files, and GZip them. Once everything is gzipped, the location visible in the source will change and so will the name. There might however be some script that don't play nicely when being compressed, but this plugin also has the ability to exclude anything you define.

Hope this helps